# How can i create tabs in listView not in designer but in runtime code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor:

```
lvnf = new ListViewNF();
lvnf.Location = new Point(250, 18);
lvnf.Size = new Size(474, 168);

this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
```

After setting the size i want to add columns like: From     Subject     Date

And how do i set the listView control(lvnf) to display added items as list ?
This is how i'm adding the items in  progressChanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt.Invalidate();
            label8.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            label8.Visible = true;
            lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.From.ToString(),         //From Column
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.Subject,                 //Subject Column
              allMessages[countMsg].Headers.DateSent.ToString()      //Date Column
            }));


            countMsg += 1;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling them tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ListView to get columns with headers. One of the properties is the View, and you set it to Details, I think. Then you add columns

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Column1",100); // 100 is the column width
listView1.Columns.Add("Column2",200);
```

and so on for each column.

To add an item,

```
listView1.Items.Add("First item");
```

Then to add the subitems (in the columns) for the ith them

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Subitem1");
```

For the first item, this would be

```
listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("Subitem1");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns to `ListView` by adding it to the `Columns` property:

```
lvnf.Columns.Add("From");
lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject");
lvnf.Columns.Add("Date");
```

And to display items as a list:

```
lvnf.View = View.List;
```

But if you use this view, column headers will be hidden.